# how to get values from dictionary filtered by condition

Tags: python

Good day everyone!

please help me to tackle the following issue.

I have some dictionary

```
d = {'key1': (0, 1), 'key2': (0, 0), 'key3': (4, 7), 'key4': (0, 0), 'key5': (9, 12), 'key2': (9, 12)}
```

I'm trying to extract key/value pars that have values of (0, 0)

```
newDict = dict()
for (k, v) in d.values():
    if v == 0:
        newDict[k] = v
newDict
```

but it doesn't works...

Comment: `if v == (0, 0):`?. Note: **Your dictionary contains duplicate keys**

Comment: You're only checking if the second element in the tuple is 0, not the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare *both* elements in the tuple, so `v == (0, 0)`. You can simplify your code to use a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {'key1': (0, 1), 'key2': (0, 0), 'key3': (4, 7), 'key4': (0, 0), 'key5': (9, 12), 'key6': (9, 12)}

newDict = { k : v for k, v in d.items() if v == (0, 0) }
print(newDict)
```

Output:

```
{'key2': (0, 0), 'key4': (0, 0)}
```

Note I've corrected the duplicate key in your dictionary by changing the second `key2` to `key6`

Comment: Thanks it works fine! but the problem is that I have the same keys with different values. 'key3': (4, 7), 'key3': (0, 0)

Comment: Dictionaries *cannot* have repeating keys. If you assign `d = {'key1': (0, 1), 'key1': (5, 6) }` and then `print(d)` you will get `{'key1': (5, 6)}` as the second value overwrites the first

Comment: thanks, may be there is an option to sort the dict and then extract (0, 0)?

Comment: @AndreyAndrey I'm not sure what you mean by sorting the dict?

Comment: for k in sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=False): 
    print(k, d[k])  but it does not help :( Thanks anyway, I'll try to avoid duplication...

Comment: That won't help either - as soon as the duplicate key is encountered the old value is overwritten. You might need to use lists as your values e.g. `'key2: [(0, 0), (9, 12)]` instead? Then you could try something like `newDict = { k : v for k, v in d.items() if v == (0, 0) or (0, 0) in v }`

Answer (score 1):

Using `dict.fromkeys()`

```
res = dict.fromkeys((k for k, v in d.items() if v == (0, 0)), (0, 0))
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'key2': (0, 0), 'key4': (0, 0)}
```